# BCS in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, bcs, external-content-type

What are the features and limitations of BCS in Sharepoint online.
Can we create an external content type using Stored procedure in Sharepoint online.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Limitations include:

- There are no profile pages for external content types
- There is no offline availability or rich client integration
- There is no search integration.

You will get some good reference from below links:

- [The features of Business Connectivity Services (BCS) are distributed across different SharePoint editions.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-external-data-676e60e7-d99f-463f-a173-65e9d63538c0#__toc353550778)
- [Make an External List from a SQL Azure table with Business Connectivity Services and Secure Store](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Make-an-External-List-from-a-SQL-Azure-table-with-Business-Connectivity-Services-and-Secure-Store-466f3809-fde7-41f2-87f7-77d9fdadfc95?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#__toc350352765)
- [Manage Business Connectivity Service Applications](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-Business-Connectivity-Service-Applications-2ced10aa-db9a-4828-a7a5-e47a57c3a823)
- [Business Connectivity Services in SharePoint Online](https://www.sharepointeurope.com/business-connectivity-services-in-sharepoint-online/)

Answer (score 0):

Limitations include:

No search integration.
no rich client integration or offline availability.
there are no profile pages for external content type.