# How to conect sharepoint 2013 BCS with MySQL?

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-bcs

How to connect sharepoint BCS  with MySQL?   I try to connect BD MySQL from BCS at SharePoint Online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **SharePoint On-Prem** you can achieve this by

- Building a [custom BCS Modal via Visual studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q8qcTfdLAxg) or
- Using a third-party solution like

  - [BCS Meta Man](http://www.manula.com/manuals/lightning-tools/bcs-meta-man-for-windows/1/en/topic/walkthrough-integrating-a-mysql-database-through-odbc)
  - [CData](https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/mysql-odata-sharepoint-external-list.rst).

---

In **SharePoint Online**, you can [Create external content types for OData data sources](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-create-an-external-content-type-from-an-odata-source-in-sharepoint), Unfortunately, I am not an expert in MySql to inform you the available OData REST API for MySQL but you can check [this](https://skyvia.com/connect/mysql-odata)

**Meanwhile,** you can build an OData Service EndPoint, then consume it within a `SharePoint Hosted Add-In` or by using a `BDC Model`. Check the detail steps at [SharePoint Online OData BCS](https://lightningtools.com/bcs/sharepoint-online-odata-bcs/)

Check also

- [Manage Business Connectivity Service Applications](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-Business-Connectivity-Service-Applications-2ced10aa-db9a-4828-a7a5-e47a57c3a823#__toc338059709)
- [BCS in Sharepoint Online](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/209873/bcs-in-sharepoint-online) Limitations